# how to write filter in controller for specific values

Tags: angularjs

How to rewrite the below line of code in the controller of app.js. How can i write a function in which i filter the mustShow var for length greater than zero

```
    **choice | filter: {mustShow: 'yes'}).length > 0**

  <body ng-app="Compensation">
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div data-ng-repeat="choic in choice">
      <form>
        <input ng-model="choic.mustShow" class="label_align" type="radio"   name="customer" value="no" ng-change="change()" >
        <div class="mediumSubhead"> Information housed </div>
        <br/>
        <input ng-model="choic.mustShow" class="label_align" type="radio" name="customer" value="yes">
        <div class="mediumSubhead"> Information housed outside </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    **<div ng-show="(choice | filter: {mustShow: 'yes'}).length > 0">**
      <input name="first_name" class="text_box_space" type="text" value="" style="color: black;" size="25" width="200px">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
  var app = angular.module('EquityCompensation', []);
  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.choice = [{id: 'choic1'},{id: 'choic2'}];

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should inject `$filter`in the controller and then use it as:

```
$filter('choice')({mustShow: 'yes'}).length > 0
```

Something like this:

```
var app = angular.module('EquityCompensation', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $filter) {
    var choice = $filter('choice')({mustShow: 'yes'});
    // Do something with choice
});
```

Comment: thanks but its not working. I just want to know the length of choice.mustShow :true in controller & do some manipulation based on that . Pls can you help me